# Garbage collection loop in Game of Life

Tags: c#, performance, game-of-life

I'm working on a [Game Of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) clone as my first project. I'm still relatively new to programming, so my code is probably not really optimised.

The biggest bottleneck is in my `Start()` method, but that contains a lot of Unity3D specific methods which most people here probably don't know about. That's why I'm leaving that out.

My second bottleneck is somewhere in my `Update()` method. In here, I'm looping through my array which is currently 100 by 100 large, 10.000 in total.

I've been checking with the built-in profiler of Unity3D, and this reports that the biggest bottleneck is the garbage collection.

I also tried to put half of the loop in another thread, but that didn't work out properly, because it needs to look up cells in the other half.

If you see any other ways to improve my code, and not just the performance, feel free to let me know. But please, keep it simple, as I'm still relatively new to programming.

The relevant code:

```
void Update()       
{
    timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;                  // this will add deltaTime to timeElapsed,
    if (timeElapsed >= timeBetween)                 // until timeElapsed exceeds timeBetween, 
    {                                               // which allows a new generation to be calculated
        timeElapsed -= timeBetween; 
        if (gameState == GameState.Game_Playing)
        {               
            grid = CheckAdjacent(grid);             // draw new generation
            UpdateInformation();                    // update information variables
        }
    }
}

public static void DrawGeneration(bool[,] grid)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < gridX; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridY; y++)
        {
            cubeGrid[x,y].renderer.enabled = grid[x,y]; // enables the renderer for active cells.
        }
    }
}

private void UpdateInformation()
{
    generation++; //counts the generations
}

public static int GetAliveCells ()
{
    int i = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < gridX; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridY; y++)
        {
            if (grid[x, y]) // counts the number of alive cells
                i++;
        }
    }       
    return i;
}   

bool IsCellAlive(int adjacentCount, bool isAlive)
{
    if (isAlive)
        return liveRule.Contains(adjacentCount);
    else
        return becomeAliveRule.Contains(adjacentCount);
}

private bool[,] CheckAdjacent(bool[,] grid)
{
    int adjacentSquares = 0;
    bool[,] newGrid = new bool[gridX, gridY];

    for (int x = 0; x < gridX; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridY; y++)
        {
            adjacentSquares = 0;                

            if (grid[calcX(x - 1), calcY(y - 1)])
                adjacentSquares++;              
            if (grid[calcX(x), calcY(y - 1)])
                adjacentSquares++;              
            if (grid[calcX(x + 1), calcY(y -1)])
                adjacentSquares++;              

            if (grid[calcX(x - 1), calcY(y)])
                adjacentSquares++;
            if (grid[calcX(x + 1), calcY(y)])
                adjacentSquares++;

            if (grid[calcX(x - 1), calcY(y + 1)])
                adjacentSquares++;
            if (grid[calcX(x), calcY(y + 1)])
                adjacentSquares++;
            if (grid[calcX(x + 1), calcY(y + 1)])
                adjacentSquares++;

            newGrid[x,y] = IsCellAlive(adjacentSquares, grid[x,y]);
        }
    }       
    return newGrid; 
}

private int calcX(int x)
{
    x += gridX;
    return (x % gridX);
}

private int calcY(int y)
{
    y += gridY;
    return (y % gridY);
}
```

Comment: This is too awesome... favourited!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I would advise you to count neighbours from alive points, not for cells to be checked. Null a 100x100 int array Neighbours. For every alive cell add +1 into every neighbouring cell in Neighbours. After the pass you have number of neighbours for the every cell, but time used is about 1/4 at most, because you saved the time not counting neighbours for zero cells.
2. You are taking left neighbours for utmost left cells, for example. Out of boundaries! You are blocking this by taking a function and modulo and thus making the toroid out of plane, but thus you are counting much longer - division or modulo are slow, functions even more slow. Simply count neighbours normally for the field except boundaries, otherwards for the four sides and four corners. More to write, but less to count later.
3. If you want a shorter code, you could use a help arrays ( I have invented them for myself in 1978)

   ```
   // neighbor-vectors in xy coordinates clockwise from algebraic x axis.
   int [8] dx={1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,0,1};
   int [8] dy={0,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1};
   ```

   and in counting neighbours for a cell do:

   ```
   if(cell[x,y]>0)
   for(i=0;i<8;i++){
      x1=x+dx[i];
      y1=y+dy[i];
      if(x1>=0 & x1<100 & y1>=0 & y1<100){
          neighbours[x1,y1]++;
      }
   }
   ```
4. Count the time spent for different activities, for not to waste time on optimizing part that takes 0.1% of time.

   So you can throw off many objects, not to create them at all. Only hold 2 desk in 2x100x100 array - each time one will be active, the other will be old.  You can even count neighbours and later make living/dead cells on the same desk. No garbage collection.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Will try to implement it later, at home. With suggestion 4, do you mean to make the array [2, 100, 100], instead of 2 arrays of [100, 100]?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, thus you could easier switch from one to another. BTW, if you like some post, except thanks there are upvotes and answer markings :-)

Comment: I know ;) Was a bit in a hurry and didn't think of upvoting.

Comment: Of course, you can also make array [2] of arrays [100,100]. Choose what is more understandable. But if you make the desk as an object, that will have array and, for example, the number of generation, and/or other things, then Desk[2] array would be more natural

Comment: The garbage collection problem will go away if you allocate two grids and 'double buffer' by reading from one to the other on each generation and then back the other way on the next. That is what @Gangnus is recommending at the end of his post.

Answer (score 4):

@Gangnus made some very good suggestions. But additionally, two ideas.

1. Instead of having a grid of bool and calculate each cell, why not have an intermediate grid of int?
2. Another improvement might be to harness the power of parallel processing: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=608
   Instead of using regular for cycles, and since each iteration is independent from all other iterations, you can convert `for(int i=0; i<10; i++) { ... }` into `Parallel.For(0, 10, i => { ... });`.

This second one is more advanced than what you are looking for and specifically asked, but very interesting nevertheless. You can still disregard it and look into only the first one.

So your `CheckAdjacent` method could be:

```
private bool[,] CheckAdjacent(bool[,] grid) {
    int[,] newGrid = new int[gridX, gridY];
    Parallel.For(0, gridX, x => {
        Parallel.For(0, gridY, y => {
            if(grid[x,y]) {
                IncrementNeighbours(newGrid, x ,y);
            }
        });
    });
    bool[,] newGridBools = new bool[gridX, gridY];
    Parallel.For(0, gridX, x => {
        Parallel.For(0, gridY, y => {
            newGridBools[x,y] = IsCellAlive(newGridBools[x,y], grid[x,y]);
        });
    });
    return newGridBools;
}

// @Gangnus' code fits perfectly. YOINK! <3
// This can probably be improved; but what for, if it works perfect?
static readonly int [8] dx={1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,0,1};
static readonly int [8] dy={0,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1};
private void IncrementNeighbours( int[,] newGrid, int x, int y ) {
    for(i=0; i<8; i++){
        x1=x+dx[i];
        y1=y+dy[i];
        if(x1>=0 & x1<100 & y1>=0 & y1<100){
            neighbours[x1,y1]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I especially like the Parallel.For(). Have been looking for something similar before, but regular threading, or even GPGPU didn't work. This will probably be a large improvement in speed!

Comment: Unfortunately, Unity doesn't seem to support .NET 4.0 :(

Comment: Thank you for the compliment. I haven't even supposed the possibility to use booleans :-). Use of integers was so obvious for me, that I haven't declared it explicitly. Of course, it should be done. --- What is "YOINK <3", please ? --- I thint your idea of parallel computing would be the best realised on the graphic cards for this task. Uhm. not for this, of course, but if the desk will be 10000x10000.

Comment: @SimonVerbeke not supported? Ah well. But this `Parallel.For` seems really useful; I just learned about here somewhere here on codereview too.

Comment: @Gangnus `YOINK <3` is a "[yoink](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=yoink)" and a heart. An attempt at showing appreciation.

Comment: Even more bad luck, tried to thread my Start() function, but a specific function I use there is only allowed to be called from the main thread.

Comment: @SimonVerbeke ah well. But threading is not too important until you aim for very large boards, I think. Until then, changing the way that things are calculated ought to be enough to speed the process up - no?

Comment: Indeed :) and the Start() function being slow is apparently caused by testing the game in the editor. When I build it and run it separately, it works like a charm :)